# TypeError: Cannot read property 'caption' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to test if the following function gets called correctly.

Here is the function, using Jest and Enzyme for React Js:

```
changeCurrentColumn = (e) => {
 {
   if(e.target.value !== 'default')
   {
     const id = e.target.value
     const name = this.props.defaultData[e.target.value].caption
     this.props.setCurrentColumn({ name, id })
   }
 }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
it('changeCurrentColumn function test', () => {
 wrapper.setProps({
   defaultData:[{
      caption:"test"
   },],
 }),
 wrapper.update();
```

The error is pointing to `({target:'test'}))` :

```
expect(wrapper.instance().changeCurrentColumn({target:'test'})).toBeDefined(); 
})
```

What can I add after 'test' in order to read the property of 'caption'?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you add coma after `}` i mean

  `wrapper.setProps({
   defaultData:[{
      caption:"test"
   }, //this`

Comment: Shouldn't be `changeCurrentColumn({target:{value:'test'}})`?

Comment: Also, your props.defaultData is an array so props.defaultData[e.target.value] will only work if e.target.value is a number. Since you are comparing it to 'default' it doesn't seem to be a number...

Comment: @iLiA misspelling , forgot to erase it

Comment: @Vinicius admitted correctly you are using props.defaultData[e.target.value] and this will work only with objects (bracket notation)\

Comment: I tried to apply that before but my test did not pass. I used the answer provided below and now its working. Thanks

Comment: That's Great if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of the defaultData to object something like this.

```
it('changeCurrentColumn function test', () => {
    const event = {
        target: {
            value: "caption"
        }
    }
    wrapper.setProps({
      defaultData:{
         caption:"test"
      },
    }),
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.instance().changeCurrentColumn(event)).toBeDefined()
});
```

or pass value as 0 to get rest from the existing defaultData.

```
it('changeCurrentColumn function test', () => {
    const event = {
        target: {
            value: 0
        }
    }
    wrapper.setProps({
      defaultData:[{
         caption:"test"
      }],
    }),
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.instance().changeCurrentColumn(event)).toBeDefined()
});
```